# How do i customize nav-item element only in my active page

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to Vue.js and Nuxt and I want to have my background img (blue line in top of items)  only in my active page (e.g contact page)

[image: screenshot of my navbar-nav > nav-item elements]

this is my **HTML** code :

```
<b-navbar-nav class="text">
    <b-nav-item to="/">ACCUEIL</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item href="/#">ARTICLES</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item href="#">CARTE</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item to="/about">L'ÉQUIPE</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item to="/contact">CONTACT</b-nav-item>
  </b-navbar-nav>
```

and my **CSS** :

[image: css code]

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `nuxt-link-active` class to set the image styles on the active nav item instead of the `nav-link` which would apply it to all nav-items.

The `nuxt-link-active` is applied by default when using Nuxt.js. You can even set a custom CSS class to be applied for the active nav. You can read more about it in the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/router-links/).